# How do I get the index of the item selected from a JComboBox?

Tags: java, swing, selection, jcombobox

This is how I created my JComboBox -

```
String[] options = {"First", "Second" , "Third"};
JComboBox optionsCombo = new JComboBox(options);
```

When one of these items is selected, how do i get the index of the item which was selected ? I don't want the item the item that was selected.

Comment: Did you check the appropriate listener on JComboBox? It must be providing a method to get the selected index.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use : [`optionsCombo.getSelectedIndex();`](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/javax.swing/JComboBoxgetSelectedIndex.htm)

inside **actionListener** Like this :

```
 ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        System.out.println("Selected: " + optionsCombo.getSelectedItem());
        System.out.println(", Position: " + optionsCombo.getSelectedIndex());
      }
    };
    optionsCombo.addActionListener(actionListener);
```

Answer (score 10):

```
int index = optionsCombo.getSelectedIndex()
```

will give selected index. Use this in combo box action listener

Answer (score 8):

indexes starts from 0,1,2,.. 
if you want to get the index of selected item then do this

```
optionsCombo.getSelectedIndex()
```